# Side-by-Side plots lined up in R

Tags: r, plot, count, violin-plot

I am trying to place two plots side-by-side in `R` and have the below example.

```
library(vioplot)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rpois(100,1)
plot(x, y, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-5,5),type='n')
vioplot(x, col="tomato", horizontal=TRUE, at=-4, add=TRUE,lty=2, rectCol="gray")
vioplot(y, col="cyan", horizontal=TRUE, at=-3, add=TRUE,lty=2)
vioplot(y, col="cyan", horizontal=TRUE, at=-2, add=TRUE,lty=2)
```

With this data, I'm able to make a `vioplot` of my `x` and `y` variables. Now, for example, I want to develop bar plots of separate count data that relates to each `vioplot` on the left-hand side.

```
counts <- c(10, 20, 30)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE)
```

I've used the `mtcars` example but it could be any count data. I'm wondering if it is possible to generate these plots side-by-side so that the count plot lines up with the `vioplot` correctly. I do not need any `y-axis` labels for the count plot.

Comment: Have you tried `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`?

Comment: @Roman that allows me to put the plots side by side, but it doesn't line the violins with the bars in each plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your specifications `ggplot` is my recommendation

```
library(tidyverse)
p1 <- lst(x, y, y1=y) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  pivot_longer(1:3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) + 
   geom_violin(trim = FALSE)+
   geom_boxplot(width=0.15) + 
   coord_flip()
p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  count(gear) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, n)) + 
   geom_col()+
   coord_flip()
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

[image]

In base `R` you can do (please note, I used boxplot, but should work with viopülot either)

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
boxplot(cbind(x,y,y), col="tomato", horizontal=TRUE,lty=2, rectCol="gray")
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
        names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want to use ggplot is function ggarrange() from ggpubr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Create a sample dataset
dt <- tibble(group = rep(c("x", "y"), each = 100)) %>% 
        mutate(value = if_else(group == "x", rnorm(200),
                               as.double(rpois(200, 1))))

# Combined violin/Box plot
violins <- dt %>% 
        ggplot(aes(value, group)) +
        geom_violin(width = 0.5) +
        geom_boxplot(width = 0.1)

# Bar chart
bars <- dt %>% 
        ggplot(aes(group)) +
        geom_bar(width = 0.1) +
        coord_flip()

# Combine
ggpubr::ggarrange(violins, bars + rremove("ylab") + rremove("y.text"), ncol = 2)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
library(vioplot)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rpois(100,1)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x, y, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-5,-1),type='n')
vioplot(x, col="tomato", horizontal=TRUE, at=-4, add=TRUE,lty=2, rectCol="gray")
vioplot(y, col="cyan", horizontal=TRUE, at=-3, add=TRUE,lty=2)
vioplot(y, col="cyan", horizontal=TRUE, at=-2, add=TRUE,lty=2)

counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
        names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interesting question, which has motivates me to explore base R graphics features. I have tried to find a case where the side-by-side configuration between the violin plot and the barplot provides a meaningful relationship. The case is that I have a subset of `iris` data with various counts of the species. I want to show three statistics:

1. the counts of sampled each species, by showing barplots;
2. the spread of sepal lengths in each sampled species, by showing violin plots; and
3. the median petal width of each sampled species, by positioning the violin plots.

I follow @GW5's idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269338/place-bars-at-specific-x-axis-values-in-a-barplot) to create barplots of which the positions on the axes can be controlled. I follow @IRTFM's idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427717/how-can-i-adjust-the-axes-to-start-from-zero-origin-in-r-plot) to adjust the origins of the axes.

Here is the full code:

```
library(vioplot)

some_iris <- iris[c(1:90, 110:139), ]
ir_counts <- some_iris |> with(Species) |> table()
ir_counts
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        50         40         30 
ir_names <- names(ir_counts)
ir_colors <- c("cyan", "green", "pink")

x_vio1 <- some_iris |> subset(Species == ir_names[1]) |> with(Sepal.Length)
x_vio2 <- some_iris |> subset(Species == ir_names[2]) |> with(Sepal.Length)
x_vio3 <- some_iris |> subset(Species == ir_names[3]) |> with(Sepal.Length)

y_vio1 <- some_iris  |> subset(Species == ir_names[1]) |> with(Petal.Length) |> median() 
y_vio2 <- some_iris  |> subset(Species == ir_names[2]) |> with(Petal.Length) |> median() 
y_vio3 <- some_iris  |> subset(Species == ir_names[3]) |> with(Petal.Length) |> median() 

# `xpd = FALSE` to keep the grid inside the plotting boxes.

par(mfrow = c(1, 2), xpd = FALSE)

# The violin plots, put on the left side.

plot(NULL, 
     xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10), type = "n", las = 1, xaxs =  "i", yaxs = "i", 
     xlab = "Sepal Length (cm)", ylab = " Median Petal Width (cm)")

vioplot(x_vio1, col = ir_colors[1], horizontal = TRUE, at = y_vio1, add = TRUE, lty = 2)
vioplot(x_vio2, col = ir_colors[2], horizontal = TRUE, at = y_vio2, add = TRUE, lty = 2)
vioplot(x_vio3, col = ir_colors[3], horizontal = TRUE, at = y_vio3, add = TRUE, lty = 2)
grid()

# The texts that informs the names of the species

text(labels = ir_names, y = c(y_vio1, y_vio2, y_vio3), 
    x = c (min(x_vio1), min(x_vio2), min(x_vio3)) - 1)

# The barplots, put on the right side.

plot(NULL,
     xlim = c(0, 60), ylim = c(0, 10), yaxt = "n", type = "n", 
     las = 1, xlab = "Counts", ylab = "", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i"
)
rect(xleft = 0, xright = ir_counts[1],
     ybottom = y_vio1 - 0.3, ytop = y_vio1 + 0.3, col = ir_colors[1])
rect(xleft = 0, xright = ir_counts[2],
     ybottom = y_vio2 - 0.3, ytop = y_vio2 + 0.3, col = ir_colors[2])
rect(xleft = 0, xright = ir_counts[3],
     ybottom = y_vio3 - 0.3, ytop = y_vio3 + 0.3, col = ir_colors[3])
grid()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

In case you want to put labels on the barplots (on the right side), you can use `mtext` as follows:

```
# ... (The same code above)
mtext(text = ir_names, side = 2, at = c(y_vio1, y_vio2, y_vio3), 
      line = 0.2, las  = 1 )
```

The resulted labels:
[image]